# Cant install socket.io in aws ec2 micro instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, socket.io, npm

I have installled node.js and npm on amazon ec2 instance.Now when I am installing socket.io, its getting stucked at :

npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/redis/-/redis-0.7.3.tgz

It just get stucks there forever.

I tried all these commands -

sudo PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH npm install socket.io -g

sudo npm install socket.io -g

sudo npm install socket.io

sudo PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH npm install socket.io

I tried changing the folder to node/npm/node_modules and tried the above 4 commands but it still gets stuck.What is going wrong here ? Please help as it is giving me a headache since morning.

Comment: How long are you waiting, I have had that command take a very long time before on a micro server. And what is the OS?

Comment: If you're using CentOS, you might need to run: sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools", because redis is native code.

Comment: OS is ubuntu 32 bit...i waited for more than hour...I am having the same problem when trying to install express

Comment: @Laurent Perrin - I am having the same problem when trying to install express i.e. when executing sudo npm install express -g....it gets stuck at some 
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/commander/-/commander-0.6.1.tgz